# How to use two operands on the left side of a comparision operator in Bash

Tags: bash

This is:

```
3.8.13-68.3.4.el6uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Tue Jul 14 15:03:36 PDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

bash --version
    GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

I am familiar with the following syntax:

```
[ $VAR = "iotools" ] || [ $VAR_2 = "iotools" ]
```

where either `$VAR` should contain the value `iotools` or `$VAR_2` should  contain the value `iotools`.

Is there a way I can write like below:

```
[ $VAR||$VAR_2 = "iotools" ]
```

The idea is to save space consumed by the code and get rid of the extra code in second pair of square brackets.

Comment: Why do you want to make the code harder to read? Code doesn't consume space in any meaningful way (not in this context).

Comment: I posted just two operand's comparision in this forum. Im dealing with more than 10 here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't shorten the left hand side of the comparison. You can, however, use a pattern on the right hand side:

```
[[ iotools == @("$VAR"|"$VAR_2") ]]
```

Note that you need to use `[[ ... ]]` instead of `[ ... ]` for that to work. See *Pattern Matching* in `man bash` for details.

The variables should be quoted to prevent `VAR='a|iotools|b'` to match.

Comment: Hello, can this be used with numerical comparisions too?

Comment: @user3146086: No, but there might be other tricks. What exactly do you want to shorten?

Comment: want to be able to use it with -ge , -le , operators

Comment: Note the word "exactly".

Comment: Sorry. [[ 255 -ge @("$VAR"|"$VAR_2") ]] can I write somthing like this if I want to evaluate both variables to be greater than or equal to 255?

Comment: @user3146086: You can use bitwise or: `(( v1 | v2 >= 255 ))`. Wait, both? This work for at least one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36615/discussion-between-user3146086-and-choroba).

Comment: That would be `<= 255`. You can use bitwise or here, but only because the limit of the range is a power of 2. And only if you want the person reading the code in the future to curse you for writing obfuscated code. @user3146086

Comment: @Gilles: Are you sure? Both variables should be greater than or equal to 255, but `256 | 256` is `256`, both are greater, but the result isn't `<= 255`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using bash, that could be done using two concepts:

- There is a way to list several variables with similar name:

  ```
  VAR=iotools
  VAR_2=tools2
  VAR_3=othertools

  printf '<%s> ' "${!VAR@}"
  ```

  Will print:

  ```
  <VAR> <VAR_2> <VAR_3>
  ```
- That could be also done indirectly `${!var}` (var is a different variable than $VAR):

  ```
  for var in "${!VAR@}"; do
      printf '<%s> '  "${!var}"
  done
  ```

  Will print:

  ```
  <iotools> <tools2> <othertools>
  ```

All together will be:

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR=iotools
VAR_2=tools2
VAR_3=othertools

testvalue="$1"

for var in "${!VAR@}"; do
    if [[ ${!var} == $testvalue ]]; then
        echo "Some value matched"
        break
    fi
done
```

---

Call as this:

```
$ script iotools
Some value matched
$ script notool
$
```